# Is there Microsoft SQL Mangement studio Edit procedure command

Tags: ssms

I have around 50 databases, all identical structure.  Now I have to edit one procedure, so the process is a bit complex:

1. expand database,
2. expand programmability
3. expand stored procedures
4. right click on procedure
5. select modify

What I want to know: Is there a command that will open the modify window for a specific procedure so that my process will just be

1. select database
2. CTRL+E to execute command

When I say command I mean text in editor window, something like this

```
edit procedure 'my_procedure'
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544108/from-a-query-window-can-a-stored-procedure-be-opened-into-another-query-window

Comment: can you give comment why -1, what if there is possibility?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I misunderstand your question... but...

If you want to use SQL Server Management Studio:

Could you simply copy the ALTER statement, paste it in a new window, change the database that window is connected to, execute, change database, execute, etc.

If you want to do it faster and more repeatable, you could just save the query to a file and write a script in cmd using sqlcmd to run that script on each of your 50 databases.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

I can't imagine managing 50 databases w/ the same structure and not using scripting...

Comment: jap, they have same procedure with the same logic, but parameters inside are differenet, so i can't just alter db with the same script, because each database is related to one id in one main database, so when copying data this id is fixed and logic is a bit different, so basically I need to edit each one, not replace each one with the new code.

Comment: I see. And they don't vary in any sort of predictable way? Could you modify them programatically? In other words, if it's just different parameters, couldn't you write something to match them and make the change? Or is each one different enough that they can't be modified in this way? If so, it sounds like the problem is more deeply rooted than this, the real question may be how this can be structured in such a way that shared code is shared and not copy/paste/slightly modified.

Comment: I already modified them manually, so job is done, but i think that there should be the way to do this easily.

Comment: There probably is. It's probably somewhat complicated though and won't get at the root cause of this problem. If you have 50 dbs you're managing and scripting them to modify them wasn't part of the plan initially, the engineers of that solution should probably rethink it.

Comment: I do have to ask, are you a software engineer or a sysadmin? I ask because the solution to your problem will likely involve scripting and/or programming. If that's not something you're comfortable doing then you may want to seek assistance from someone else in your company that is.

Comment: No, that is not the case. We are using out of the box solution for shopping cart, and each shopping cart has its own database, so we have like 50 clients, and by the way we have our software where we can track things and give access to clients so we have custom procedures that are called once purchase is done, and that procedure is copying data from one shopping cart db into our db, and also that procedure is different for each shopping cart, not by functionality but by hardcoded parameters inside it. So that is the case.

Comment: So if you had an index of those differences then you could script generation of the alter scripts. Essentially, you'd have a list of the dbs mapped to a list of the fields and their names or whatever other metadata you'd need to generate the proper alter query for each one, then you'd generate them and script running them against each database. This sounds like a very solvable problem if you're a software engineer.

Comment: Lol Aron, When I need software solution I don't ask for it on Stackoverflow.com, This update had to be done that day once I asked, and it should be really quick so that is the reason I have asked it.

Comment: I understand the question as: from a query window can you force a stored proc editor open.  Redesigning the database, scripting the changes etc etc don't really answer that question.

Comment: wow dude, did you really hop onto a 2 year old question and -1 an answer that was trying to address the root problem to a question that had no actual answer? What a valuable member of the community you are :)